# Switching Scenes in SpriteKit Swift 2

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, skscene

I have been trying to make a game in sprite kit and I want to implement a start screen with a play button that takes you to the actual game. I have seen many ways to do it but most of them use swift 1 and are not up to date
Here is the code to my function

```
func switchScene()
{
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "PlayScene")
    let transition = SKTranstion.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
    self?.view.presentScene(scene, transition)
}
```

where PlayScene is a swift class that extends SKScene

Comment: So what is the actual problem ? ;) Are there any errors ? Have you created both StartScene.sks and PlayScene.sks ? And you have a typo, it is `SKTransition`, not `SKTranstion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my games, I use this:

```
// Setting a size (or else it may look like its zoomed in)
var selectView = BallSelect(size: view!.bounds.size) 
// Setting a file for that scene
selectView = BallSelect(fileNamed: "BallSelect")! 
// Setting the scale
selectView.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill 
// Transitioning scenes wit a specific transition
self.scene?.view?.presentScene(selectView, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithColor(color, duration: 1))
```

Tell me if it works :)

Comment: I had to do some tinkering with the unwrapping, but (if let statement with selectView = PlayScene(fileNamed:"")) but besides that it worked pretty well

Answer (score 0):

What is important here is to have two .sks files because you are using SKNode's `fileNamed:` convenience initializer. So, if you haven't done this already, go to

> File -> New -> File...-> Resource->SpriteKit game scene

and add a new .sks file. Now, because `fileNamed:` is declared as failable initializer, it can return nil:

```
public convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)
```

You should use optional binding to access your new scene in a safely way:

**StartScene.swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let scene = PlayScene(fileNamed: "PlayScene"){
            let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
            view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }     
}
```

Comment: I did some testing with this and the button mechanism I implemented worked but the program won't get past the "if let scene = PlayScene" statement. P.S. thanks for the help so far